# Update JList with Custom Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I have attempted to convert my program to a GUI. I have 2 custom Arraylists of type subject (b & m) I need to setListData to the custom object type b when the B button is pressed and m when the M button is pressed. So far my List looks like

```
LabelCoreSubs.setText("Core Subjects:");
        ListCoreSub.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = {};

            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            public String getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ListCoreSub);
```

I can call this custom arraylist through ArrayList b = B.getCores(); how would i get this arraylist to display in my Jlist. I have also attempted to change the JList type to Subject but with no luck.

How do I update my JList to display each list on a button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setListData()` method of `JList` only works for an Array or a Vector, so you can't use it with an `ArrayList`.

So you can:

1. Create a `DefaultListModel`.
2. Use the `addAll(...)` method of the `DefaultListModel` to copy the items of the `ArrayList` into the model.
3. Use the `setModel(...)` method of the `JList`.

A better approach is to not create two ArrayLists to hold the initial data. Instead just create a `DefaultListModel` and add the data directly to the model. This way the data is only in one place. And to change the data displayed in the `JList` you just use the `setModel(...)` method.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass b.toArray() then update the Jlist?

Comment: Or use DefaultListModel<JListValues> model = new DefaultListModel<>()
 for(JListValues val : array)
         model.addElement(val);

Comment: @xanthon23, 1) the first approach would create a fixed model. That is you will not be able to dynamically update the model once is is created. 2) Why reinvent the wheel? There is already a method that does that for you in one statement. Why would you want to write you own loop? Use whatever approach meets your requirements.